# How do i use intl outside a function, because i need to have this this text translated to 3 languages

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import { useIntl } from 'react-intl';

const intl = useIntl()     

export const MTM = [
  {
    value: 1,
    label: intl.formatMessage({id: 'TEXT.120'})
  }
]
```

trying to translate a text outside of a function but i can find any way to do it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Functions in react that start with "use" are hooks,

You'll need to turn your MTM const into a react component

Hooks can only be used in a react component